Log Cepstral Distance proof using Parseval's theorem
The magnitude spectrum of $x(n)$ is given by
$$ S(w) = \sum_{n = -\infty }^{+\infty} x(n) \cdot e^{-jwn} $$
The $log S(w)$ can be expressed as
$$ log S(w) = \sum_{n = -\infty }^{+\infty} c_n \cdot e^{-jwn} $$
where $c_n$ is called the cepstral coefficient of $S(w)$ .
From inverse Fourier transform we have
$$ c_n = \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} log S(w) \cdot e^{jwn} \cdot \frac{dw}{2 \pi} $$ and
$$c_0 = \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} log S(w) \cdot \frac{dw}{2 \pi} $$
The rms log spectral distance is related to the $L_2$ cepstral distance by
$$d_2^2 = \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} \left| log S(w) - log S'(w) \right|^2 \cdot \frac{dw}{2 \pi}
      = \sum_{n = - \infty}^{ + \infty} ( c_n - c_n')^2  $$
How do you prove this using Parseval's theorem?
I know that Parseval's theorem links energy of a signal in both time and frequency domain by the relation,
$$ \int_{- \infty}^{+\infty} |f(w)|^2 dw = 2 \pi \cdot \int_{- \infty}^{+\infty} |f(x)|^2 dx $$
But I could not see the proof flowing from here.
